# How can I boot Pi zero with SSH over USB

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot, ssh, linux

I am trying to boot a Raspberry Pi Zero into a terminal using a laptop over `ssh` by connecting it to laptop with a USB cable.

I followed the methods explained on the internet that involves editing the config file and one other file. I did the same, but it still does not seem to work. I am installing Raspbian Jessie (Feb 2017 version) on a Raspberry Pi Zero first model, the one without a camera connector. It's connected using a USB cable to a laptop.

After connecting, it does not show up in drives and I can't `ssh` using putty with the IP "raspberrypi.local" (but the videos and tutorials on the internet does show Raspberry Pi Zero as a USB drive and they can `ssh` into it using "raspberrypi.local"

Tell me if I am wrong somewhere or what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SD card is newly created, by default SSH is not enable on the first boot. SSH can be enabled by placing a file named 'ssh', without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card. This is newly implemented feature since Nov 2016 release, whatever video you are viewing might be created early, or have done so without mentioning.

Comment: Yeah I knew that but how do I create a new file without extension in Windows 10. Windows does not allow you to create a new file without specifying its type(extension). Any suggessions. Well thanks for the answer.

Comment: Did you try `notepad ssh.` (or whatever text editor your using other than notepad), this should create a file without extension.

Comment: Okay so its working. I created a blank file with name ssh and with no extension and that worked. Thanks again!